# React Native search for words starting with text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I search, I only want words starting with A or B....Z

Sample:

```
A           Au         B          Be
Allow       August     Banner     Bemol
August                 Bemol
Animal
```

```
  searchFilter = (text) => {
    const newData = dizi.filter((item) => {
      const listItem = `${item.name.toLowerCase()}`;
      const textData = text.toLowerCase();
      return listItem.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      diziler: newData,
    });
  };
```

Comment: What is passed parameter `text` here?

Comment: Is the issue that this is only checking one letter, and you want to check more than one?

Comment: There is a built-in string method `.startsWith` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith  it is case-sensitive, so you'll want to use `.toLowerCase()` on both the text and the item.  Since you are just looking that the first letter you could do `text[0]?.toLowerCase() === item.name[0]?.toLowerCase()`.  Or you can use regex which is shorter to code but I think performance-wise it's slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in string method [`.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) that you can use.  It is case-sensitive, so you'll want to use `.toLowerCase()` on both the `text` and the `item.name`.

```
  searchFilter = (text) => {
    this.setState({
      diziler: dizi.filter((item) => 
       item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase())
      );,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
searchFilter = (text) => {
  const newData = dizi.filter((item) => {
    if (
      item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith("a") ||
      item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")
    ) {
      const listItem = `${item.name.toLowerCase()}`;
      const textData = text.toLowerCase();
      return listItem.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    }
  });
  this.setState({
    diziler: newData,
  });
};
```